# Difference in record counts between my SQL editor and Python psycopg2 query

Tags: python, sql, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I am running the exact same redshift query copied from a sql editor to python. In python I have tested counts from pandas.read_sql and direct psycopg2 cursor.execute queries. On the SQL editor side, I have tested the counts in dbeaver, beekeeper and mysqlworkbench. I have stripped out all joins to simplify the query with the same variance occurring between the environment types. I have checked getdate() in all environments and see the same timestamp to rule out any difference in timezones between environments. If it were a few records, I could attribute it to timing, but it is in the 20-30k range for a 6-month window. What else should I be checking?

simplified query:

```
select count(distinct u.customerid)
from users u
```

Python setup:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(f"dbname={DB} host={HOST} port={PORT} 
user={USER} password={PWD}")
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('''  select count(distinct u.customerid)
                    from users u
        ''')
result = cursor.fetchone()
print(result)
conn.close()
```

Comment: You're mentioning `GETDATE()` and 6 months window, but neither of your queries uses either of these things. Did you forget to add the condition?

Comment: I had dates in the original query when I first noticed the variance. To further rule out any date calculation issues I removed them and reflect that in the simplified query.

Comment: just to rule out the obvious: are you using the same database, host, port and user in both your setups? Redshift has row-level security which might affect the data as seen by different users. Can you please run `EXPLAIN` in both your clients and see if the plans match?

Comment: also, what type does your customerid have? if it's a character type of any kind, it might be a matter of collation which matters for `DISTINCT`. Do the counts without `DISTINCT` match?

Comment: it is a varchar. I tested count(*), count(customerid) and just `select customerid` all with the same variance to the original query

Comment: It is unclear to me what the variance is? To your question add the exact number for each client(Python, non-Python) for a given run.